# Dice Roll Array PHP Issue

Tags: php

I have never used PHP before, but basically this program is supposed to run 36,000 times, and each time the two dice are rolled, the total number gets a "tally." Right now, it outputs whichever number it has rolled with "36,000 tallies" instead.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php 

 $dice = (rand(1,6) + rand(1,6));
 $roll = array();

     for ($result = 0; $result < 36000; $result++){

        if ($dice == 2){
        $roll[2]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 3){
        $roll[3]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 4){
        $roll[4]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 5){
        $roll[5]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 6){
        $roll[6]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 7){
        $roll[7]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 8){
        $roll[8]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 9){
        $roll[9]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 10){
        $roll[10]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 11){
        $roll[11]++;
        }
        if ($dice == 12){
        $roll[12]++;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You probably need to initialise your array to zeros first and roll the dice within the loop!

Comment: Your dice roll is outside of the loop so you'll not get a new roll each time through the loop

Comment: @MattinWashington Thank you very much, it now works! Appreciate it.

Comment: You probably want to use [`random_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) instead of `rand`

Comment: @Griz are you sure you accepted the best answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize all your possibilities and add the dice roll inside the loop.

http://codepad.org/nQfGZ3bR

```
<?php 
$roll = array();
$roll[2] = 0;
$roll[3] = 0;
$roll[4] = 0;
$roll[5] = 0;
$roll[6] = 0;
$roll[7] = 0;
$roll[8] = 0;
$roll[9] = 0;
$roll[10] = 0;
$roll[11] = 0;
$roll[12] = 0;

for ($result = 0; $result < 36000; $result++){
    $dice = (rand(1,6) + rand(1,6));
    $roll[$dice]++;
}

var_dump($roll);
```

Output:

```
array(11) {
  [2]=>
  int(962)
  [3]=>
  int(1999)
  [4]=>
  int(3019)
  [5]=>
  int(3923)
  [6]=>
  int(4929)
  [7]=>
  int(6083)
  [8]=>
  int(5076)
  [9]=>
  int(3971)
  [10]=>
  int(3006)
  [11]=>
  int(2017)
  [12]=>
  int(1015)
}
```

Comment: rigged dice, 8 is far to popular :-)

Comment: perhaps this is a little nicer: `$roll = array_fill(2, 11, 0);`

Comment: @Dagon yah, I'm sure there's some optimization in there. Feel free to edit and improve the answer.

Comment: There are 36 roll permutations for two 6 sided dice.  Which results in the following frequencies for pair totals:
`array ( 1 => NULL, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 3, 5 => 4, 6 => 5, 7 => 6, 8 => 5, 9 => 4, 10 => 3, 11 => 2, 12 => 1 )`.  The totals 6 and 8 should have the same chance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the *$dice = rand...* line inside the *for* loop

Comment: Also instead of the horrendous if thing in there OP should just do `$roll[$dice]++`

Comment: @Alan Thank you for this!